# How to get actual value of observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, rxjs6

In a service class a method has to pass the current device serialNumber. Using ngrx the device$ can be subscribed to get actual one, but that doesn't feel good. What is a best practice for this situation?

```
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {
  public device$: Observable<Device>;
  public device: Device; // feels 'redundant'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private store: Store<DeviceState>,) {
    this.device$ = this.store.select(DeviceSelectors.getCurrentDevice);
    this.device$.subscribe((device: Device) => {
      this.device = device; // feels bad
    });
  }

  regenerate() : Observable<Object> {
    if (environment.production) {
      const url = `${environment.url}/devices/${this.device.serialNumber}/regenerate`;
      return this.http.get(url) as Observable<Object>;
    } else {
      return of({});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can use the async pipe if you are gonna show it in the html.

Comment: usually I move the subscription to the component , in my opinion is not a good practice have the observable and the raw value in the service (duplicated variable in memory ).

Comment: @EduardoVargas it's a service class, so not shown in html. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ricardo I agree it's not a good practice. That's why I posted the question :). The other option is indeed passing the device from html to the component, dispatch it to the action, catch it in the ngrx/effects and pass it to the service method :(.

Comment: Possibly use switchMap? Pass the result of the first http call to the second, so everything would reside in the regenerate method. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use mergeMap to achieve what you want:

```
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {
    public device$: Observable<Device>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private store: Store<DeviceState>,) {
        this.device$ = this.store.select(DeviceSelectors.getCurrentDevice);
    }

    regenerate() : Observable<Object> {
        if (environment.production) {
            return this.device$
                .pipe(
                    first(),
                    mergeMap(device => this.http.get(`${environment.url}/devices/${device.serialNumber}/regenerate`))
                );
        } else {
            return of({});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@NielsSteenbeek , Usually what I do is obtain the value from the store on the fly  (when calling regenerate() ) you can use flatMap to archive what you want

```
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<DeviceState>,) {}

    regenerate() : Observable<Object> {
        if (environment.production) {
            return this.store.select(DeviceSelectors.getCurrentDevice)
                .pipe(
                    first(),
                    flatMap(device => this.http.get(`${environment.url}/devices/${device.serialNumber}/regenerate`))
                );
        } else {
            return of({});
        }
    }
}
```